# Understanding Tensor Notation $\chi\in\mathbb{R}^{I\times J\times K}$

Tags: notation, tensors, index-notation

I'm very new to the world of Tensors, and feel like I am thinking about a specific notation very incorrectly. Say you have $$\chi\in\mathbb{R}^{I\times J\times K}$$ The way I have been thinking about a Tensor of this sort was as short video where say we have a sequence of say K=10 images which are all I=20 by J=20 pixels each. From this, I would imagine the tensor as a sequence of 10 matrices, which are each 20x20 in size. Is that correct? If not, is there a more intuitive way to think through the notation?

Comment: The word "tensor" has different (but related) meanings in different contexts. But the type of multidimensional array you described is one common definition of the word "tensor", especially in the machine learning world. (Perhaps a pure mathematician might think that a mere multidimensional array does not deserve to be called a "tensor".) You could also think of your multidimensional array as storing a 3 dimensional image, such as a CT or MRI image. Or perhaps you could imagine recording the temperature at each point in a 3D grid in space.

Comment: @littleO thank you for the response. As you mentioned, I am coming from the machine learning world and find it much more intuitive to think of tensors as multidimensional arrays if that truly is an appropriate "equivalent" to tensors

Comment: I used to resist using the word "tensor" to mean a multidimensional array, but then I realized that the book Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan, which is like the Bible of numerical linear algebra, uses the word "tensor" in this way. So I guess it's fine. But we should remember that the tensors that pure mathematicians and physicists work with are something different (but their tensors can be represented by multidimensional arrays, just as a linear transformation can be represented by a matrix).